# CSS getting injected into index from somewhere after theme/custom CSS is loaded, overriding all of my CSS

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

Using the inspector tool i can see that some CSS is getting injected/generated from somewhere (which i don't know where) which is overriding my own css.

I've tried several things from using a child theme, setting various CSS to "!important", tried editing bootstrap.css, tried to disable the appearance customizer (as the options getting injected seem to be your options set in the customizer, however removing the customizer does nothing).

I quite literally just want a stylesheet that i can code in that doesn't get overridden, however that seems impossible, as this css/code gets injected/generated last no matter what i do.

The code getting injected is the code labeled/commented as /*Text Color*/ and /*Featured Color*/ and so on.

Sorry for the massive code dump.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/betasite/xmlrpc.php">

<!-- WP_Head -->
<title>betasite &#8211; Just another WordPress site</title>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="betasite &raquo; Feed" href="http://localhost/betasite/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="betasite &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://localhost/betasite/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost\/betasite\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.8"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a,b){var c=String.fromCharCode;l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,a),0,0);var d=k.toDataURL();l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,b),0,0);var e=k.toDataURL();return d===e}function e(a){var b;if(!l||!l.fillText)return!1;switch(l.textBaseline="top",l.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return!(b=d([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819]))&&(b=d([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]),!b);case"emoji":return b=d([55358,56760,9792,65039],[55358,56760,8203,9792,65039]),!b}return!1}function f(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var g,h,i,j,k=b.createElement("canvas"),l=k.getContext&&k.getContext("2d");for(j=Array("flag","emoji"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},i=0;i<j.length;i++)c.supports[j[i]]=e(j[i]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[j[i]],"flag"!==j[i]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[j[i]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(h=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",h,!1),a.addEventListener("load",h,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",h),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),g=c.source||{},g.concatemoji?f(g.concatemoji):g.wpemoji&&g.twemoji&&(f(g.twemoji),f(g.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/css/bootstrap.css?ver=3.3.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='photoswipe-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/css/photoswipe.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='photoswipe-skin-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/css/default-skin/default-skin.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flickity-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/css/flickity.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='olivo_lite_style-css'  href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/style.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='olivo_lite_style-inline-css' type='text/css'>

/* Text Color */
body{
    color: #777777;
    background: rgb(242,188,101);background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(242,188,101,1) 0%, rgba(226,40,107,1) 61%, rgba(52,21,65,1) 100%);background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(242,188,101,1) 0%,rgba(226,40,107,1) 61%,rgba(52,21,65,1) 100%);background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(242,188,101,1) 0%,rgba(226,40,107,1) 61%,rgba(52,21,65,1) 100%);
}
h1:not(.site-title), h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a, h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover,
.blog-hype #content .post .entry-header .post-title a:hover{
    color: #222222;
}
/* Link Color */
a{
    color: #FF3A91;
}
a:hover{
    color: #D43078;
}

/*============================================
    // Featured Color
    ============================================*/

    /* Background Color */
    .pagination .current,
    .pagination li.active a,
    .section-title::before,
    .ql_primary_btn,
    #jqueryslidemenu ul.nav > li > ul > li a:hover,
    #jqueryslidemenu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
    .olivo-home-slider-fullscreen .slider-fullscreen-controls .prevnext-button,
    .pace .pace-progress,
    .woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li a:focus, 
    .woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li span.current,
    .woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li a:hover,
    .ql_woo_cart_button:hover,
    .ql_woo_cart_close,
    .woocommerce .woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul .woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link.is-active a,
    .woocommerce_checkout_btn,
    .post-navigation .nav-next a:hover::before, .post-navigation .nav-previous a:hover::before,
    .woocommerce #main .single_add_to_cart_button,
    .olivo-contact-form input[type='submit'],
    .woocommerce-cart .wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button,
    .woocommerce #payment #place_order, .woocommerce-page #payment #place_order,
    .contact-form input[type="submit"],
    .portfolio-load-wrapper .portfolio-load-more,
    .olivo-preloader .olivo-folding-cube .olivo-cube::before,
    #ql_load_more
    {
        background-color: #FF3A91;
    }

    /* Border Color */
    .pagination li.active a,
    .pagination li.active a:hover,
    .section-title::after,
    .pace .pace-activity,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li.current, .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li:hover,
    .woocommerce_checkout_btn,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories .ql_product_search:hover .woocommerce-product-search #woocommerce-product-search-field,
    .touch .ql_woocommerce_categories .ql_product_search:hover .woocommerce-product-search #woocommerce-product-search-field
    .olivo-contact-form input[type='text']:focus,
    .olivo-contact-form input[type='email']:focus,
    .olivo-contact-form textarea:focus
    {
        border-color: #FF3A91;
    }

    /* Color */
    .pagination li.active a:hover,
    .single .post .entry-footer .metadata ul li a,
    #comments .comment-list .comment.bypostauthor .comment-body,
    #respond input,
    #respond textarea,
    #footer h2, #footer h3, #footer h4,
    .widget_recent_posts ul li h6 a, .widget_popular_posts ul li h6 a,
    .style-title span,
    .ql_filter ul li.active a,
    .ql_filter ul li a:hover,
    .ql_filter .ql_filter_count .current,
    .portfolio-slider .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-title,
    .portfolio-slider .portfolio-slider-controls .prevnext-button,
    .portfolio-multiple-slider .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-title,
    .portfolio-multiple-slider .portfolio-slider-controls .prevnext-button,
    .single-portfolio-container .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-title,
    .ql_cart-btn:hover,
    .ql_cart-btn:focus,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li.current, .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li:hover,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li a:hover,
    .woocommerce #main .products .product .price, .woocommerce-page .products .product .price,
    .woocommerce a.added_to_cart,
    .woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-product-rating,
    .woocommerce #main .price,
    .woocommerce #main .single_variation_wrap .price,
    .woocommerce-cart .cart .cart_item .product_text .amount,
    .ql_woo_cart_close:hover,
    #ql_woo_cart ul.cart_list li .product_text .amount,
    #ql_woo_cart .widget_shopping_cart_content .total,
    .woocommerce_checkout_btn:hover,
    .woocommerce .star-rating,
    .widget .amount,
    .post-navigation .nav-next a,
    .post-navigation .nav-previous a,
    .welcome-section .welcome-title,
    .question,
    .olivo-contact-form .olivo-contact-form-text,
    .olivo-contact-form input[type='text'],
    .olivo-contact-form input[type='email'],
    .olivo-contact-form textarea,
    #jqueryslidemenu ul.nav > li > ul > li.current_page_item > a, 
    #jqueryslidemenu ul.nav > li > ul > li.current_page_parent > a,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li.current a,
    .woocommerce p.stars a,
    .ql_cart-btn .count,
    #jqueryslidemenu ul.nav > li > a:hover,
    .olivo-portfolio-type.single article .metadata a
    {
        color: #FF3A91;
    }

    /* Fill */
    .entry-header .svg-title li .olivo-vertical-simple .st0,
    .page-header .svg-title li .olivo-vertical-simple .st0,
    .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow,
    .olivo-home-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot .is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st0,
    .portfolio-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st0,
    .portfolio-multiple-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st0,
    .olivo-home-slider .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow,
    .olivo-home-slider .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow,
    .olivo-home-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st0
    {
        fill: #FF3A91;
    }

    /* Stroke */
    .entry-header .svg-title li .olivo-vertical-simple .st1,
    .page-header .svg-title li .olivo-vertical-simple .st1,
    .olivo-vertical path,
    .ql-svg-inline .g-svg,
    #jqueryslidemenu .current_page_item a, #jqueryslidemenu .current_page_parent a,
    .olivo-home-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot .is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st1,
    .ql_filter .ql_filter_count .olivo-count-svg path,
    .portfolio-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st1,
    .portfolio-multiple-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected .olivo-vertical-simple .st1
    {
        stroke: #FF3A91;
    }

    /* Darker Background Color */
    .no-touch .ql_primary_btn:hover,
    .no-touch .woocommerce #main .single_add_to_cart_button:hover,
    .no-touch .olivo-contact-form input[type='submit']:hover,
    .no-touch .woocommerce-cart .wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button:hover,
    .no-touch .woocommerce #payment #place_order:hover, 
    .no-touch .woocommerce-page #payment #place_order:hover,
    .contact-form input[type="submit"]:hover,
    .no-touch .portfolio-load-wrapper .portfolio-load-more:hover,
    .no-touch #ql_load_more:hover,
    .no-touch .contact-form input[type="submit"]:hover
    {
        background-color: #E73483;
    }

    /* Faded Background Color */
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-hover,
    .olivo_lite_team_member .olivo_lite_team_hover
    {
        background-color: rgba( 255, 58, 145, 0.88 );
    }

    /* Footer Background Color */
    #footer
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .footer-top ul li
    {
        border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    /* Logo Color */
    .logo_container .ql_logo
    {
        color: #222222;
    }



    /* Typography */
    body{
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .logo_container .ql_logo,
    .post-navigation .nav-next a span, .post-navigation .nav-previous a span
    {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a,
    .metadata,
    .pagination a, .pagination span,
    .ql_primary_btn,
    .ql_secundary_btn,
    .ql_woocommerce_categories ul li,
    .sidebar_btn,
    .woocommerce #main .products .product .product_text, .woocommerce-page .products .product .product_text,
    .woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li a, .woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li span,
    .woocommerce #main .price,
    .woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li,
    .woocommerce-cart .cart .cart_item .product_text .price,
    #jqueryslidemenu ul.nav > li,
    .sub-footer,
    .ql_filter ul li,
    .post-navigation .nav-next a, .post-navigation .nav-previous a,
    .read-more,
    .portfolio-load-wrapper .portfolio-load-more,
    .woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb,
    #main .woocommerce-result-count,
    #ql_load_more,
    .woocommerce #main .single_add_to_cart_button,
    .contact-form input[type="submit"],
    #respond .form-submit #submit-respond,
    .woocommerce-cart .actions input[type='submit'],
    .woocommerce-cart .actions input[type='submit'],
    .woocommerce-cart .wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button,
    .woocommerce #payment #place_order, .woocommerce-page #payment #place_order
    {
        font-family: Inconsolata;
    }


    /*============================================
    // Retina Images
    ============================================*/




</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='olivo_lite_google-font-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=%22Source+Sans+Pro%22%3A400%2C500%2C700&#038;ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='olivo_lite_google-font-headings-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata%3A400%2C700&#038;ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/betasite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/betasite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/betasite/wp-content/themes/olivo-lite/js/modernizr.min.js?ver=1'></script>
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://localhost/betasite/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/betasite/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/betasite/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.9.8" />
        <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
<!-- End WP_Head -->

</head>
```

Comment: A lot of it is prefixed with `olivo-` so I'd wager it's coming from your theme _olivo-lite_. Reach out to them to ask if you can suppress it through a filter.

Comment: Note that customizer is just a user interface, disabling it just disables the UI. All the plumbing is still there

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the theme and ran a `grep` on it. It turns out the styles are generated by `/inc/scripts/style.php` in a function called `olivo_lite_get_custom_css`. I suppose you could overwrite that function.